# Dup on ActiveRecord objects - can access child objects, but not through join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following associations:

```
Teacher hasMany Students hasOne Desk
```

When duping `Student` objects like so:

```
@new_teacher.students = teacher.students.collect{ |student| student.dup }
```

I can run `@new_teacher.students[0].desk` and get the `desk` object.

However, the following code returns an empty array. It seems like the `desk` object is not available through a `join`. This is all before saving the object. It just seems odd I'm able to access it above, but not through a `join`.

```
teacher.students.joins(:desk)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like expected output because a `dup` call doesn't necessarily do a deep dup.

A gem like [deep_cloneable](https://github.com/moiristo/deep_cloneable) might suit your needs.